# Differential in terms of $T_pX \simeq \left(\mathfrak{m}_p/ \mathfrak{m}_p^2\right)^\ast$

Tags: differential-geometry, tangent-spaces

I am studying different definitions of the tangent space to a manifold $X$ in a point. When we identify $T_pX \simeq \left(\mathfrak{m}_p/ \mathfrak{m}_p^2\right)^\ast$, how can we express the differential $dF_p$ of a differentiable map $F:(X, p) \to (Y, q)$? The "standard" definition, seeing $T_pX$ as a space of derivations of $\mathcal{C}^\infty_X(p)$, would be $dF_p(\delta)=\delta F^\ast_p$ for every $\delta \in T_pX$.

My idea is that if we call
$\alpha_q=\alpha: T_qY \to  \left(\mathfrak{m}_q/ \mathfrak{m}_q^2\right)^\ast$ and $\beta_p=\beta: \left(\mathfrak{m}_p/ \mathfrak{m}_p^2\right)^\ast \to T_pX$ the two isomorphism defined by $$\alpha(\delta)(f+ \mathfrak{m}_q^2)=\delta(f), \quad \beta(\omega)(g)=\omega(g-g(p)+\mathfrak{m}_p^2) \quad \forall \delta \in T_qY, f \in \mathfrak {m}_q, g \in \mathcal{C}^\infty_X(p),\omega \in \left(\mathfrak{m}_p/ \mathfrak{m}_p^2\right)^\ast, $$ then the differential  $ \left(\mathfrak{m}_p/ \mathfrak{m}_p^2\right)^\ast \to \left(\mathfrak{m}_q/ \mathfrak{m}_q^2\right)^\ast$ should be $\alpha \circ dF_p \circ \beta$, that is, the bottom row of the following diagram:

$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
{T_pX} @>{dF_p}>> T_qY\\
@A{\beta_p}AA @VV{\alpha_q}V\\
\left(\mathfrak{m}_p/ \mathfrak{m}_p^2\right)^\ast @>{??}>> \left(\mathfrak{m}_q/ \mathfrak{m}_q^2\right)^\ast
\end{CD}

However I find difficulties finding an explicit expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A differentiable map $F : X \to Y$ such that $F(p) = q$ induces a pullback map $\mathfrak{m}_q \to \mathfrak{m}_p$ (the pullback along $F$ of a function vanishing at $q$ vanishes at $p$). This pullback map sends $\mathfrak{m}_q^2$ to $\mathfrak{m}_p^2$ and so induces a map on quotients $\mathfrak{m}_q/\mathfrak{m}_q^2 \to \mathfrak{m}_p/\mathfrak{m}_p^2$, and then you take the linear dual of this map.

Comment: So your claim is that the differential is the transpose of the pull-back? How do you prove this? And is it true that it equals $\alpha dF_p\beta$ in my diagram?

Comment: Probably there's a nicer way but you can just pick a chart around both $p$ and $q$ and work in coordinates and verify that you get the Jacobian this way. In any case it's practically the only natural construction available.

Comment: You can also use natural pairing $\langle\ ,\ \rangle:T_pX\times(\mathfrak{m}_p/\mathfrak{m}_p^2)\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by $\langle\delta,[f]\rangle=\delta(f)$ (with $T_pX$ defined as the space of derivations) and show directly that the two spaces are dual to each other, and that the differential and pullback satisfy $\langle d_pF(\delta),[f]\rangle=\langle\delta,F^*([f])\rangle$.

Comment: Yes this can be easily done also without working in coordinates. Call $\mathfrak{F}_p^{\ast}:\mathfrak{m}_q/\mathfrak{m}_q^2 \to \mathfrak{m}_p/\mathfrak{m}_p^2$ the map induced by the pull-back. Then we have $$\alpha(dF_p(\beta(\omega)))(g+\mathfrak{m}_q^2)=dF_p(\beta(\omega))(g)=(\beta(\omega) \circ F_p^\ast)(g)=\beta(\omega)(gF)=\omega(gF-gF(p)+\mathfrak{m}_q^2)=\omega\circ F_p^\ast(g + \mathfrak{m}_q^2)= \mathfrak{F}_p^{\ast, \top}(\omega)(g + \mathfrak{m}_q^2)$$ for any $g \in \mathfrak{m}_q$, implying that $$\alpha_q \circ dF_p \circ \beta_p = \mathfrak{F}_p^{\ast, \top}.$$